# Is the way that visual studio references and uses .proto files different on native machine from when building the project when using docker?

Tags: .net, .net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've .proto files A.proto, B.proto and common.proto. Both A and B import common.proto where all the protos are in the same folder and added links in visual studio (mac),
like so:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="..\Protos\common.proto" GrpcServices="Server">
      <Link>Protos\common.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
    <Protobuf Include="..\Protos\A.proto" GrpcServices="Server">
      <Link>Protos\A.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
    <Protobuf Include="..\Protos\B.proto" GrpcServices="Server">
      <Link>Protos\B.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
  </ItemGroup>
```

the common.proto is referenced like so

```
  import "Common.proto";
```

Visual studio (mac) builds, and generates C# classes from the proto message and runs with no problem.

I created a docker file myself (not with docker support in visual studio). Below is the folder structure of the application

```
src
 |- Dockerfile
 |-Project1
     |-project1.csproj
     |- Protos
         |-common.proto
         |-A.proto
         |-B.proto
```

When docker is able to copy the project and restores the project but fails for the same project that worked when run in visual studio with the message:
"Could not make proto path relative : error : ../Protos/common.proto:..."

What could be the issue?

project info
.Net 7
Grpc.AspNetCore Version="2.54.0"
Grpc.Tools Version="2.54.0"

1. I changed the import path in A.proto and B.proto to import "Protos/Common.proto" but visual studio complains that the  in common.proto are duplicated. Also, specified the AdditionalImportDirs="Protos" in the project file for the .protos references but VS complains of duplicated objects

2.I moved the protos folder to the same one as the project and that also failed then updated the Dockerfile accordingly but that also did not work.

3. I only imported the common.proto in A.proto and the imported A.proto in B.proto and again visual studio cannot find the messages of common.proto in B.proto

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with building gRPC for .NET **but** it would be helpful if you include the `Dockerfile` that you're using. This error arises when (`protoc`) compilation is unable to determine a fully-qualified folder path for all of the protobuf sources. In this case `common.proto` (Elsewhere you reference this as `Common.proto`!?). MSBuild appears to permit relative paths (`..\Proto\A.proto`) which is confusing but these may be getting concatenated to somewhere.

Comment: You need to determine the set of `proto_path`'s. A `proto_path` is a file-system folder that contains protobuf sources. Within each `proto_path` file-system folder you may have a heirarchy of folders that must represent the `package`'s used by your sources. If you're not using `package`'s, then all your protobuf sources will be in this folder. Then, you will need to define (a) the `proto_path` folder; (b) the set of protobuf sources.

Comment: MSBuild may use a default folder (the current project folder) for the `proto_path`. If not, this must be defined somewhere. Usually, compilation (`protoc`) then combines each `proto_path` (a) with  each protobuf source (b) to determine a fully-qualified (absolute) folder path and this avoids the error you're receiving.